# How do I .focus a form input area with a click on the form button?

Tags: javascript, forms, button, input, focus

So I have a search form in the `nav` menu of my website, and I'd like to have the search button once clicked on, to redirect to the search input, and not to the archive/search section of the website.

I wrote this:

```js
function l() {
  document
    .getElementsByClassName("search-button")[0]
    .addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      var t = document.getElementsByClassName("search-input")[0];
      t.value.length < 2 && (e.preventDefault(), t.setFocus());
    });
}
l();
```

```html
<form role="search" class="search-form" method="get" action=# placeholder="Searching for …" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Searching for …'">
  <input class="search-input" name="s" type="text" placeholder="Searching for ..." onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Searching for ...'">
  <button type="submit" class="search-button" title="Search Blogs">
 </button>
</form>
```

But it doesn't seem to do much.
I thought the placeholder maybe would count as a t.value.lenght>2 but even without a placeholder (input already focused) the button redirects to the search page, which should be stopped by e.preventDefault() shouldn't it?

Maybe is there a CSS way of stopping the button to link to the search page?

Thanks

Comment: Do you ever call the function `l()`?

Comment: The placeholder doesn't count as a value. It's something that's displayed when there is no value.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Barmar, I think https://codesandbox.io/s/l705x947jq should summarise the code.

Comment: added `l();` function call, seems like the `e.preventDefault(),` does work now, but still doesn't focus on the input bar...

Comment: There's no function `t.setFocus()`, it's just `t.focus()`. When I correct that it works for me.

Comment: Thank you very much @barmar ! you are right! `t.focus()`